# Length parse href with html simple dom

Tags: php, html

I want to get href of a link in a page.

For this I use html Simple Dom : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

On the page parsed, the href is "/?pageid=304&matchid=28906".

So for make link I add the base of url

```
$link = "http://www.hltv.org" . $info->href;
```

So now I make vardump :

```
$link_2 = "http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=304&matchid=28906";
var_dump($link);
var_dump($link_2);
```

And the result is :

```
string(49) "http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=304&matchid=28906"
string(45) "http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=304&matchid=28906"
```

Questions :

- Why not the same length ?
- Why when I execute with curl, the $link not work but $link_2 works fine ?

---

**UPDATE :**

htmlspecialchars_decode() on the parsed href works fine.

The & in url is a `&amp;` but we see just a &.

Thanks to @chris85

Comment: Are you viewing the generated source? My guess is that in the DOM the `&` is `&amp;`.

Comment: `string(30) "/?pageid=304&matchid=28908"`

Comment: It's the result of `var_dump($info->href);`

Comment: Yes, I see your code. Where are you viewing it though, in a browser?

Comment: Yes in chrome browser

Comment: View the source of the page.